# Flask session variable does not keep values from one call to the other

Tags: python, session, flask

I've been trying to get this to work for a while now and I don't know what to try. I made a Flask app and I'm testing it now on localhost. I run a server for my client on localhost:8000 and another for the Flask app on localhost:8080, then I use flask-cors to enable cross-domain requests. All seems to work fine, the app does its job. However, when it comes to storing values in its `session`, it suddenly fails. Here's the key parts of the code:

```
def retrieve_tokens(self, session, code):
    # Get tokens from ORCID given a request code
    headers = {'Accept': 'application/json'}
    payload = dict(self._details)
    payload.update({
        'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
        'code': code,
    })

    try:
        r = post(self._url + 'oauth/token',
                 data=payload, headers=headers)
    except ConnectionError:
        return None

    # Save them (if no error has occurred)
    rjson = r.json()
    if 'error' not in rjson:
        print rjson
        session['login_details'] = rjson
        print session['login_details']

    return r.json()

def get_tokens(self, session, code=None):
    # Retrieve existing tokens, or ask for new ones
    if 'login_details' in session and code is None:
        print session['login_details']
        return session['login_details']
    elif code is not None:
        # Retrieve them
        return self.retrieve_tokens(session, code)
    else:
        # Something went wrong
        return None
```

As you can see, there's some `print` debug calls in there. When `retrieve_tokens` is called everything goes fine; most importantly, the second `print` gives the same result as the first (namely, a JSON object with all the requested tokens). However `get_tokens` obstinately returns `None`. Any clue what I may be doing wrong? A few things I ruled out:

- my `app_secret` is set up and should be fine. I use a static one, loaded from a JSON file (so that I can put it into `.gitignore` for my repository)
- setting `SERVER_NAME` doesn't help
- importing `session` in the main file and passing it to these functions (that are inside another file) instead of importing it directly in the external file doesn't change anything
- using `session.modified = True` after changing the value doesn't change anything

What can I try? Nothing seems to work. Is it a problem with running on localhost? A bug? I'm using Chrome on Ubuntu 16.04, if that helps.

Comment: I think change the title "How to synchronise two servers?"

Comment: Shoot, I didn't think of that, maybe running the thing on two separate servers creates the problem? I did it because I didn't know how to test it locally otherwise, but in the real use case it's not going to be like this. Anyway not changing the question because that's not what I want to do, but it might be the reason for my problems.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are assigning a value within an if-statement. So if the condition of the if-statement is not given you will not assign a value that your will use later and your code will fail with that. Try to change the if-statement by a if-else statement to ensure this field of session will have a value.

Comment: As written, this should be a Comment. As per SO guidelines, Answers need to include the exact code necessary to solve the problem, not just hints at when you should try. Please edit to include a code implementation of your suggestion.